# Object classification by color

Tags: python, opencv, image-recognition

I want to make a program to **classify the occupation** of people **by the color** of their **clothes** from a video.

For example, if the person is wearing the white coat, there he is a doctor.

[image]

If he is wearing in blue, then he is a police

[image]

I have tried to code for **cutting the image into the upper half** for easier color recognition

```
image= image[:len(image)/2]
```

And then, I change the image to **HSV** and make it more **smooth**. I analysis it by the range of color.

```
dst = cv2.bilateralFilter(image,9,75,75)
# Conver the image from RGB to HSV
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(dst, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
channels = split(hsv)
ratio = ((float)(count(channels)) / (float)(total_number_of_pixel))
```

However, I found out that the **ratio value is very small.** I think that it is because of the b**ackground noise.**

I am looking for the help of how to eliminate the background noise. Is there any more suitable method to classify the occupation?

Comment: Why don't you do a edge detection first and then take out the relevant part  of image based on your criteria.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Is edge detection similar to feature matching? I have tried to use the feature matching in opencv, however, it cannot recognize it. My program is recognizing the people from a cam, so I cannot extract the "relevant part" from the image, as it is quite small.

Comment: these 2 are different, but from a laymen point of view, you can basically use a combination of the edge detection and feature matching. I am not really an expert on this but what you can actually do is use a edge detected filter to get the edges and then use feature matching to filter out the "human" . Once the human is out you can apply a simple filter at the mid point of whole image to detect the color .. does this sounds like a idea?

Comment: Ya, it sounds good. Is this the only way for occupation classification? As if we just consider the mid point of the image, there will be a huge mis-classification

Comment: you can actually prepare a filter like 4x4 and map it over the upper half to get the right classification; this is still not very perfect way but it will give u a start

Comment: Oh ya, you are right. Maybe I can carry out the K-mean alg. to group the color. You know, there is "infinite many white color"

Comment: Nice , i guess you got the point